# Getting JFlex and Cup to work together

Tags: java, compilation, jflex

I'm trying to implement a parser with JFlex and Cup. Right now I'm just trying to get them to compile the simple example program found at the link below.

> http://www.cs.rit.edu/~pal6640/cup-example/simple-expr.html

To create the `parser.java` and `sym.java` file from the `cup` script I run:

```
java –jar java-cup-11a.jar parser.cup
```

Next, I use `JFlex.jar` to create the lexer java file:

```
java –jar JFlex.jar lexer.lex
```

Then to compile:

```
javac –classpath java-cup-11a.jar Yylex.java sym.java parser.java
```

The compile command throws **12 errors**. They all say

> cannot find the symbol variable scanner

I think that I have all my environment variables set correctly.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Java CUP distributes two jar files: [executable standalone Jar-package](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/java-cup-11a.jar) and [CUP runtime-library to use in conjunction with CUP generated parsers](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/java-cup-11a-runtime.jar). The parser generated by CUP needs the second one. Therefore your third command should be something like

```
javac –classpath java-cup-11a-runtime.jar Yylex.java sym.java parser.java
```